# Acquisition of meat/dairy status from contact with clean utensil

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

According to kashrut laws, if there is a container of cold, pareve food (such as a bag of flour or a jar of peanut butter), does using a clean dairy or meat utensil to scoop out some amount of the product cause the *remainder* of the product in the container to become dairy or meat? Does the material of the utensil matter? Does it matter whether the utensil is a spoon or a knife?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: Revised to remove personal aspect.

Comment: Glad to see you recieved compent halachic advice on this matter: http://dinonline.org/2019/09/03/acquisition-of-meatdairy-status-from-contact-with-clean-utensil/